# ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 in Jinja2 template

Tags: sqlite, google-app-engine, jinja2

I've just migrated from the Python 2.5 to the 2.7 runtime, and most of server I've written runs fine. However I'm occassionaly seeing this odd stack trace (I've hacked it down for brevity):

```
ERROR    2013-04-23 10:40:15,598 wsgi.py:235]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "templates/querystart.html", line 30, in top-level template code
{% for session in sessions %}
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

I've not imported sqlite3 myself, and I don't rely on it. The code that's calling it is pretty simple (perhaps bordering on the dumb side of things):

```
class UserIdQuery(BaseHandler):
def get(self):
    sessionQuery=Session.all().order("userid")
    template_values = {
        'sessions': sessionQuery,
    }
    self.render_template('querystart.html',**template_values)
```

The above simply extends the below (taken from a very helpful migration tutorial)

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
@webapp2.cached_property
def jinja2(self):
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

def render_template(self, filename, **template_args):
    self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **template_args))
```

Anyone know what might be triggering the import error? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Appengine uses sqlite for the datastore, my bet is your python2.7 installed on OSX is missing the sqlite binary library.  Do a quick test, start a python interpreter (outside of appengine) and try to import sqlite3

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>>
```

If that fails you know you have an incomplete 2.7 runtime installed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, both within Sublime Text 2's SublimeREPL and iterm, and importing sqlite3 seems to work fine.  I have installed sqlite3 since then, though not restarted the server.  That's a good tip though, it's good to know what's causing the ImportError to appear in the first place.

Comment: hmm sqlite is normally installed as part of the standard python2.7 runtime, and shouldn't need to be installed separately.  Well under windows and linux, I don't know about OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and fixed it.

I was running python 2.7.3 that I installed from Ninite.com.

Uninstalled python, downloaded and installed 2.7.5 installer directly from python.org and problem has gone away.